# Web-приложение: архитектура и инструмент

Tags: веб-программирование, база-данных, кроссплатформенность, архитектура

Добрый день! Нужен совет для разработки web-приложения:

- приложение работает с (небольшой) БД
- есть online версия, которая работает через браузер
- есть offline (локальная) версия приложения, которая работает без соединения с интернет также как и online, с локальной копией (части) БД, не теряя основной функционал
- желательно, чтобы для offline версии не было необходимости переписывать код (Java?)
- желательно, чтобы offline версия была мультиплатформенной, для Windows, Linix, Mac, Android

Имеется опыт разработки приложений только под Windows. Какие есть идеи по выбру архитектуры, инструмента разработки, СУБД для online и offline версии?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/service-worker-libraries/ - стартовый набор от гугла для оффлайн версии . вэб

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут альтернатив мало, ибо кроссплатформенное - это всегда:

1. Java (+jsp для браузера, или апплеты, пр.)
2. Чистый, незамутненный web :) я имею ввиду html5+js, со всеми его прибамбахами в меру поддержки браузерами. Web Storage, Application Cache, WebSQL, Indexed DB, LocalStorage, SessionStorage и прочие вкусности.
3. Может быть тут еще что-то, но вот так навскидку не скажу - настоящей кроссплатформенности нет ни у кого боле...

Для СУБД можно поиспользовать (если база небольшая) SQLite, MySQL, DB2

В случае Java можно использовать внутреннюю/встроенную БД

PS: у Гугла же есть возможность работы с почтой в браузере offline.